# A better way to get count from foreign keys in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-orm

How does Django's ORM handling the following in terms of performance and what is the best approach to my problem.....

I have the two models `Project` and `ProjectVote`. I want to provide a `model method` on `Projects` to display the number of votes each project has when I display them.

However I'm worried! The code below just seemed like a performance drain. If I load in all projects and call the vote_count method on each project I would guess that hit the DB many more times then I need to! Is there a better way? Thanks

```
class Project(RewardBase):
    """
    Represents a Project.
    """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80, help_text="Name of the project")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, editable=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def vote_count(self):
        """
        Return the number of votes this project has had.
        """
        return ProjectVote.objects.filter(project=self.project).count()


class ProjectVote(RewardBase):
    """
    Represents a vote for a Project.
    """

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', related_name="votes")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to tally all the projects in one go, try this query:

```
ProjectVote.objects.values("project_id").annotate(count=Count("project_id"))
```

That should generate a result like `[{'project_id': 123, 'count': 5}, ...]`. You could put this in a custom `Manager` method that returns an appropriate data structure for your needs.

Also note that your single-project `vote_count` can be simplified to `self.votes.count()`.

Comment: To summarize the difference between this method and @knbk's: If you need access to `Project`, either for filtering or after the fact, use that technique; if not (that is, if all you need are the `Project` ids), use this one, since it avoids the additional `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2):

You can annotate the `Project` model with the number of related `ProjectVote`s like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Project.objects.annotate(vote_count=Count('votes'))
```

This will set a `vote_count` attribute on each `Project` model instance. This can be combined with any amount of filters, order_by queries etc. If you filter on an attribute on `ProjectVote` (such as `votes__user=current_user`) *before*  annotating, only the filtered results will be present in the vote count.

This will result in a single query that will both fetch all `Project` instances and the count of related `ProjectVote` instances.